# how to find mysql database last updated date

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to show site last updated date on website home page.
I have more than 80 tables in my database.
Using codeigniter

> SELECT UPDATE_TIME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME

but it shows every table updated date.

Comment: what did you mean last update of your database? why you dont use this `SELECT UPDATE_TIME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1`

Comment: i have tried it but it am getting update time as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If timestamp is not what you can do, which would be ideal, then you can try a workaround.

Codeigniter has a [last_query](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html) function, which pretty much returns the last executed query. If you find that function and either extend it, or find and actually alter the method to store ONLY update functions (or some other logic for storing it, maybe another method called from inside of it), and when you call it, you get the query executed. From there, it is string manipulation.

Comment: yeh i got that later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Accept the answer, maybe? =)

Answer (score 0):

"to show site last updated date on website" I actually would write a date into the database at the time its updated. Or have a "updated" timestamp for every content item. Then you simple query the items and find the last updated.

Comment: i know what ur saying but content wise is not feasible in my case .